# Stackoverflow quota for a day

Tags: stackexchange, stackexchange-api

I'm using stackoverflow in my meteor application,

I'm calling api directly from my code like below

```
HTTP.call("GET", urlString,{params:{site:"stackoverflow"}},function(error,result)
            {
                 console.log(result.data);
               });
```

I'm not using any oauth or client id secret id in my calls.

In the response, I'm getting a variable called `quota`. with maximum pings 300

Is that means I can only call the api for 300 times, I want more than that, I'm even ready to pay for it.

Is there a way to increase that number.
Thanks

Comment: Refer https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Answer (score 0):

You are [throttled](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) because you have not registered your application. If you [register](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) your application, you will receive a quota increase to 10,000 hits per day. You will want to read the [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) documentation on how to utilize the keys you receive from registering your application.